# How to check max length of input field?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to check max length in angular ? For example if i have this field:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control font28 centerText" ng-model="ticketPin" maxlength="10" only-digits mask="9999999999" restrict="reject" clean="true" />
```

can i say something like

```
if($scope.ticketPin.maxlength == 10)
{...}
```

Comment: `$scope.ticketPin.length` will give you the length of the data entered by user. What exactly do you need? The max length attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You could access the DOM with jQuery or vanilla JS in your controller, but this is generally frowned up in Angular. I suppose a more Angulary way of doing it would be to bind a variable to [`ng-maxlength`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

```
$scope.myScopeVariable = 12;
```

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-maxlength="myScopeVariable" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use jQuery:

```
$('input[ng-model="ticketPing"]').attr('maxlength');
```

It is generally not a good idea to access DOM elements in only directives, not services or controllers.